# How to clear FragmentBreadCrumbs From Fragment BackTrace?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, breadcrumbs

When I want to set **BreadCrumbTitle** I do it like:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction_action = fragment_Mgr.beginTransaction();
...
transaction_action.setBreadCrumbTitle("BreadCrumbTitle");
```

But the problem is that the breadCrumb stays there all the time, **how can I remove it?**

Answer (score 0):

No you cant remove that. and even it cant be changed also if locale changes so it is also not recommended. [It is written here See API Documentaion for proof.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setBreadCrumbTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: If helped mark answer as helpful so we can know you are satisfied with answer.